# What's the difference between the object tag and include tag in HTML?

Tags: html, ssi

What is the most obvious difference between using this:

```
<object type="text/html" data="http://www.somepage.com/menu.html"...>
```

And this:

```
<!--#include virtual="/menu.html" -->
```

Am I okay to assume both an object tag and a server side include do pretty much the same? Or when is it better to use one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested both, and from the looks of it the `server side include` will take up a page's whole body tag, but the server from the website must be able to support it (most Windows servers can't and should use `.shtml` files as a last resort)

The `object` tag, however, while older and supported pretty much anywhere needs a width and height to take up the whole screen, or else it will only occupy only a small portion of the screen, similar to an `iframe`